# Geoserver WMS character representation error (UTF-8)

Tags: geoserver, wms, mapinfo, getfeatureinfo

I created a layer that is connected to an Oracle DB table. I can access the layer as WMS and as WFS. The character representation is correct in the WFS but has errors in the WMS service. I used Qgis and MapInfo for testing and I have the same problem with both.

Screenshot MapInfo info tool (**WMS**):

[image]

Screenshot MapInfo info tool (**WFS**):

[image]

I recognized that I have the same problem with all my WMS layers where german umlauts are used. In the Geoserver global settings the charset is set to UTF-8. How can I fix this?

EDIT: I tested the same WMS with ArcGIS Explorer and Gaia. Both can display the character correctly. The problem seems to be the software that is used to access the WMS... I will let you know when the ticket is answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Error was not caused by the Geoserver. MapInfo (Version 12.0) was not able to display the characters correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Check making a call with the browser and the developer tools of the browser that the GetFeatureInfo response is being declared as UTF-8.

Or directly try to modify the html/xml [GetFeatureInfo templates](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/GetFeatureInfo/index.html) to enforce the client display [the results in utf-8](http://augusttown.blogspot.com.es/2010/01/customize-wms-getfeatureinfo-response.html) adding a line like this in the header:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></meta>
```

Of course, in the client you should use the html/xml info formats.

Comment: This did not work. We found out that the characters are displayed correctly using Gaia3 and ArcMap Explorer. So the problem might not be caused by the geoserver.

Answer (score 0):

so there are many things to check:

1. in the first line of SLD coding: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`
2. check that the workspace is on UTF-8
3. check that the store (that is connected to the workspace) is on UTF-8

[image: the three checks of right endoding]